# How to avoid security issue in with `#{str}`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, code-injection

It is a convenient way to write code like this:

```
str = "John"
p "Welcome, #{str}"
# => "Welcome, John"
```

In real Rails app, it is possible that `str` be intentionally written to terminate the current expression and start malicious code. How can I avoid using `#{}` in cases we do need to mix string with evaluated function values? e.g.: `"Hello, #{foo(param)}"`.

Comment: not sure why you'd have to ever come up with an alternative. just make sure you massage the data correctly

Comment: I don't see the problem `str = "foo(param)"; p "Welcome, #{str}"` will just print the string `"foo(param)"`, it won't evaluate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"#{str}"` is safe with this caveat: the *format* itself must not be user-supplied. On the other hand, the *value* (the evaluation of `str`) being interpolated in is not of (eval) consequence.

So, to make this code unsafe is actually fairly hard:

```
fmt = "doBadStuff()"
eval('"Welcome #{' + fmt + '}"')
```

Of course, *the resulting string (from the initial question) must be used correctly* (e.g. [database placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/ruby.html) or quoted correctly for HTML) to avoid standard injection vulnerabilities; *but the imagined vulnerability does not exist*.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing `"foo#{bar}baz"` does is to apply `to_s` on `bar` and concat the result with `foo` and `baz`. If you get user input through a textbox or the like, the input will already be a string. If `bar` is already a string, `to_s` on it will return itself. Concatenation will result in a string. It could happen that the resulting string look like `rm -rf`, but unless you further do things like `system` or `eval` on it, nothing else would be done with the string.